# Count of rows at fixed time intervals and associated percentages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame in python:

| id | entry_time | other_columns |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16:02:04 | other_values |
| 2 | 15:02:04 | other_values |
| 3 | 10:32:04 | other_values |
| 4 | 21:22:44 | other_values |
| 5 | 09:02:04 | other_values |
| 6 | 11:02:04 | other_values |

Given the following time intervals, I want to count the rows of the previous dataframe according to their time of entry. In addition, I want to get a column with the percentage (2 decimal places) for the resulting `count` column.

| time_slot | count | percentage |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00-03:00 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 03:00-06:00 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 06:00-09:00 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 09:00-12:00 | 3 | 50.00 |
| 12:00-15:00 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 15:00-18:00 | 2 | 33.33 |
| 18:00-21:00 | 0 | 0.00 |
| 21:00-00:00 | 1 | 16.67 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
 data = {'id': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6},
 'entry_time': {0: '16:02:04',
  1: '15:02:04',
  2: '10:32:04',
  3: '21:22:44',
  4: '09:02:04',
  5: '11:02:04'},
 'other_columns': {0: 'other_values',
  1: 'other_values',
  2: 'other_values',
  3: 'other_values',
  4: 'other_values',
  5: 'other_values'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    id  entry_time  other_columns
0   1   16:02:04    other_values
1   2   15:02:04    other_values
2   3   10:32:04    other_values
3   4   21:22:44    other_values
4   5   09:02:04    other_values
5   6   11:02:04    other_values
```

---

**Code**

use `pd.cut`

```
bins = range(0, 25, 3)
labels = ['{}:00 - {}:00'.format(str(i).zfill(2), str(i + 3).zfill(2)) for i in bins[:-1]]
s = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df['entry_time']).dt.hour, bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
pd.concat([s.value_counts(), s.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)], keys=['count', 'percentage'], axis=1).reindex(labels).rename_axis('timeslot')
```

result:

```
timeslot     count  percentage
00:00 - 03:00   0   0.0
03:00 - 06:00   0   0.0
06:00 - 09:00   0   0.0
09:00 - 12:00   3   50.0
12:00 - 15:00   0   0.0
15:00 - 18:00   2   33.3
18:00 - 21:00   0   0.0
21:00 - 24:00   1   16.7
```

other way

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['entry_time']).dt.hour.floordiv(3)
df1 = pd.concat([s.value_counts(), s.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)], keys=['count', 'percentage'], axis=1).reindex(range(8)).fillna(0)
df1.index = df1.index.map(lambda i:'{}:00 - {}:00'.format(str(i * 3).zfill(2), str(i * 3 + 3).zfill(2)))
df1.rename_axis('timeslot')
```

result:

```
             count  percentage
timeslot        
00:00 - 03:00   0.0 0.0
03:00 - 06:00   0.0 0.0
06:00 - 09:00   0.0 0.0
09:00 - 12:00   3.0 50.0
12:00 - 15:00   0.0 0.0
15:00 - 18:00   2.0 33.3
18:00 - 21:00   0.0 0.0
21:00 - 24:00   1.0 16.7
```